# How to get event/exception from timer event handler back to main thread in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, timer

I have windows service application (no winforms). In Main method I started timer. Timer elapsed event handler is running in new thread(?). Is any easy way how to throw exceptions from timer elapsed event handler back to main thread?

I was trying to handle exceptions in handler body and rise custom events, but when I restart the main process on rising this event, now runs 2 processes doing same things simultaneously.

How can I get event or exception information form timer event handler thread back to main thread?

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Timers;

namespace TestingConsoleApplication.Model
{
    static class ThreadExceptionTester
    {
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)]
    public static void Run()
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

        Timer Timer = new Timer(1000);
        Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerEventHandler);
        Timer.Start();

        try
        {
            throw new Exception("1");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catch clause caught : " + e.Message);
        }

        //throw new Exception("2");
    }

    static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
        Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
    }

    static void TimerEventHandler(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Throwing from timer event handler");
        throw new Exception("timer exception");
    }
}
}
```

This write on console this:

```
Catch clause caught : 1
Throwing from timer event handler
```

And then program crash with unhandled exception on throw new Exception("timer exception"); If I uncomment throw new Exception("2"); Exeption is processed and on console is also "Catch clause caught : 2". In other words, timer exceptions are not processed by MyHandler.

Comment: Your code cannot possibly repro what you describe, and doesn't, any exceptions raised in a Timer.Elapsed event handler are swallowed without any diagnostic.  It is not a very good class, favor System.Threading.Timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event for subscribing to all exception events.

**EDIT:**
According to MSDN:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0 and earlier, the Timer component
>   catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the
>   Elapsed event. This behavior is subject to change in future releases
>   of the .NET Framework.

i have looked into source of System.Timers.Timer from .NET4 using dotPeek and there still no changes since 2.0, so consider using System.Threading.Timer instead.

Comment: I did try implement it by example in the link, but exceptions trowed in timer elapsed event handler are uncaught (.NET 4).

Comment: Yes, but this timer shut down the program on exception in its handler. Exception is however available in AppDomain.UnhandledException. This is hardtime. :-)

Comment: @Fanda try set [ExitApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.unhandledexceptioneventargs.exitapplication.aspx) flag to false for preventing application exit

Comment: It is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.aspx. As I read all the stuff, I am getting to thinking exceptions are not the best way how to communicate between threads. :-) I am thinking about using events. I hope there wont be obstacles like this. :-) Thank you Alexander.